# Laravel 5 : How to redirect to login page on invalid URL input?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm new to laravel 5. I just want know how to protect routes from invalid URL input. An example of an invalid input URL is shown below:

```
 http://localhost:90/csadcsvs
```

If someone enters invalid URL from my laravel project, I just want to redirect to login page.

Comment: i want to redirect to login page

Comment: Your question is not clear, what do you call "this kind"?

Comment: @PeterPan666 - i just want to redirect to login page  if someone enter invalid url from my laravel project.

Comment: If someone enters unspecified/unhandled route, an exception will be thrown. Open `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` and handle the redirection there.

Comment: example in stackoverflow. ill enter url  like this http://stackoverflow.com/vsjdvnjsndjvks

Comment: @Mjh - thank you, it works

Comment: No problem, have fun using Laravel :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works by adding

```
 return redirect()->guest('auth/login')
```

instead of the below in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`

```
 return parent::render($request, $e)
```

It is used as shown below:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
   if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
          $e = new NotFoundHttpException($e->getMessage(), $e);

    }
     return redirect()->guest('auth/login');

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Route::get('/{any}','Pagecontroller@index');
```

any url which is not declared in the route will be accepted by {any} and the will be controlled back to index.

Answer (score 0):

Hey create middleware using this [LINK](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware) this is my **auth** middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                return redirect()->guest('login');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

in here if you use this middle ware like this without sign in you can't access your url **csadcsvs**you will redirect to login page this is the way protect url in laravel

```
Route::get('csadcsvs',['middleware' => 'auth', function () {

}]);
```

hope this will help you :)